# Sqlite data provider .net error: Different SQL response command prompt vs. SQLite ADO.NET Provider

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, sqlite-net

I found a problem that perhaps is a bug in SQLite ADO.NET Provider.

The environment is Windows 7 Pro, using Visual Studio 2012 Professional, with Visual Basic.net & ADO.NET 2.0. Data Provider Version 1.0.66.0 - v2.0.50727.

To test I am using a simple SQLite database with just one table (“operations”).

The data looks like:

```
ID|TYPE|CODE|SIGN|DATE 
15|TE|MC_02|ACME|2007-02-13
132|TE|MC_02|ACME|2009-01-16
190|TE|MC_02|ACME|2011-02-18
596|M|MC_02|MA|2009-06-17
703|M|MC_02|MA|2009-11-30
796|M|MC_02|MA|2010-06-10
898|M|MC_02|NQ|2011-07-04
929|M|MC_02|NQ|2011-12-02
980|M|MC_02|NQ|2012-01-02
1011|M|MC_02|NQ|2012-06-29
1061|M|MC_02|NQ|2012-12-05
1062|M|MC_02|AB|2000-01-01
```

If I run the following SQL SELECT statement with the command prompt:

```
D:\DB>sqlite3 test.db

Sqlite>SELECT *, MAX(DATE) FROM operations WHERE CODE = 'MC_02' GROUP BY TYPE;
```

I have (correctly):

```
1061|M|MC_02|NQ|2012-12-05|2012-12-05 
190|TE|MC_02|ACME|2011-02-18|2011-02-18
```

Instead, if I use the below VB.net code (just a Form with a Button):

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim arrSelect As New ArrayList
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim strConnection As String = "data source= D:\DB\test.db"
        Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT *, MAX(DATE) FROM operations WHERE CODE = 'MC_02' GROUP BY TYPE"
        Dim strRecord As String = ""
        arrSelect = SelectSQL(strConnection, strQuery)
        If arrSelect IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each value As Array In arrSelect
                strRecord = ""
                For j As Integer = 0 To value.Length - 1
                    strRecord &= value(j) & "|"
                Next
                Console.WriteLine(strRecord)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

    Function SelectSQL(ByVal strConn As String, ByVal strCommand As String) As ArrayList
        Try
            Dim SQLconnect As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection()
            Dim SQLcommand As New SQLite.SQLiteCommand
            SQLconnect.ConnectionString = strConn
            SQLconnect.Open()
            SQLcommand = SQLconnect.CreateCommand
            SQLcommand.CommandText = strCommand
            Dim SQLreader As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()
            Dim listLoc As New ArrayList
            Dim nc As Integer = SQLreader.FieldCount
            Dim arrLoc() As Object
            While SQLreader.Read()
                ReDim arrLoc(nc - 1)
                For j As Integer = 0 To nc - 1
                    arrLoc(j) = SQLreader.Item(j)
                Next
                listLoc.Add(arrLoc)
            End While
            SQLcommand.Dispose()
            SQLconnect.Close()
            Return listLoc
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

You have this result (wrong):

```
1062|M|MC_02|AB|2000-01-01
190|TE|MC_02|ACME|2011-02-18
```

Anyone has already encountered this behavior?

Is this a bug of the Data Provider? Or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of query work only in SQLite 3.7.11 and later, so you should update the provider to version 1.0.80.0 or later.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the delay, the last time I could not devote much time to this work. I am passed to the Data Provider v 1.0.84 and in the test reduced project everything seems to work. When I have time I will apply it to the real project. Thank you again. Greetings.